# Удалить 1й айтем при открытии Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Мне нужно, чтоб при развертывании `Spinner` 1й пункт "Выберете..." скрывался или убирался из массива, привязанного к `Spinner`.
Пробовал установить visability GONE 1-му айтему - скрывается не полностью, если из метода `getDropDownView()` вернуть `null` - вылетит с ошибкой.
Пробовал отслеживать событие открытия Spinner с помощью `View.OnClickListener` - тоже вылетел с ошибкой:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
        at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:774)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочее решение похоже на [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609239/224411), но вместо того, чтобы переопределять `getCount()`, мы просто скрываем стартовый айтем с помощью `setVisibility()` и `setHeight()`. Стартовый пункт размещаем в конце списка.

```
class CustomAdapter<Str> extends ArrayAdapter<Str> {
    private final Context cntxt;
    private final Str[] objects;

    CustomAdapter(Context cntxt, int resource, @NonNull Str[] objects) {
        super(cntxt, resource, objects);
        this.cntxt = cntxt;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup p) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) super.getView(pos, convertView, p);
        tv.setTextColor(pos == objects.length - 1 ? ContextCompat.getColor(cntxt, R.color.spinnerTxtColor) : Color.BLACK);
        return tv;
    }

    public View getDropDownView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup p) {
        if (pos == objects.length - 1) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
            tv.setVisibility(GONE);
            tv.setHeight(0);
            return tv;
        } else return super.getDropDownView(pos, null, p);
    }
}
```

При инициализации Спиннера устанавливаем последний айтем:

```
spinner.setSelection(city.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение следующее. В данных создаем **последний** пункт с той надписью, которая должна быть в закрытом спиннере (в примере это *select city ..*). Позицию в спиннере переводим на этот пункт. Теперь у нас в закрытом состоянии все отображается как надо.

**MainActivity^**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    Spinner spinner;
    private String[] city = { "Moscow", "New York", "Berlin", "Select city .." };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, city);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setSelection(city.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Теперь, для скрытия этого пункта при раскрытии списка просто уменьшаем счетчик пунктов в адаптере на один, переопределив метод `getCount()`

**CustomAdapter:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    String [] city;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, String[] city) {
        super(context, resourceId, city);
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return city.length - 1;
    }
}
```

Скрыть можно и первый пункт, но этого не нужно делать, так как такое решение усложнит логику, что связано с тем, что будет несоответствие позиций списка и позиций в спиннере, так как хотя пункт и скрыт, у него остается индекс.
То есть получится так, что для позиции данных `city[1]` спиннер будет возвращать `position = 0`. При размещении стартового пункта в конце списка мы избегаем этой проблемы. Кроме того, так решение намного проще и требует намного меньше кода.

Comment: При повороте экрана элемент "Выберете.." меняется на предпоследний (((

Comment: @Соколов такого не должно быть.