# Как задать разные цвета для подсказки и выбранного значения для spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, hint

У меня есть выпадающий список (spinner) и мене нужно сделать так, чтобы подсказка была серой, а когда я выберу какой-то вариант из списка, текст в ячейке ставал черным. У меня получается или всё чёрное или всё серое.

Я использую вот такой код для заполнения списка и осуществления подсказки:

```
        Spinner month = findViewById(R.id.month);
            String[] plants = new String[]{
                    "Month",
                    "January",
                    "February",
                    "March",
                    "April",
                    "May",
                    "June",
                    "July",
                    "August",
                    "September",
                    "October",
                    "November",
                    "December"
            };
            final List<String> plantsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(plants));
            final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, R.layout.spinner_, plantsList) {
                @Override
                public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                    if (position == 0) return false;
                    else return true;
                }
                @Override
                public void setDropDownViewResource(int position) {
                    if (position == 0) return false;
                    else return true;
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                            ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                    if (position == 0) tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    else tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    return view;
                }
            };
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_);
            month.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

[image: ОБЬЯСЕНЕНИЕ]

Comment: Цвет надо менять в getView() - закрытом состоянии, а не getDropDownView() - открытом. Реализация спиннера с подсказкой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790973/177345

Answer (score 0):

Вот так у меня получилось (цвет подсказки меняется в методе getView):

```
val spinnerAdapter = object : ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_white_item, items) {

        override fun isEnabled(position: Int): Boolean {
            // Disable the first item from Spinner
            // First item will be used for hint
            return position != 0
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            val view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
            if (view is TextView && position == 0) {
                view.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.gray))
            }
            return view
        }

        override fun getDropDownView(
                position: Int,
                convertView: View?,
                parent: ViewGroup
        ): View {
            val view: TextView = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent) as TextView
            //set the color of first item in the drop down list to gray
            if(position == 0) {
                view.setTextColor(Color.GRAY)
            } else {
                //here it is possible to define color for other items by
                //view.setTextColor(Color.RED)
            }
            return view
        }

    }
```

R.layout.spinner_white_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_margin_triple"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_mega"
    tools:text="Please select the item" />
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]